# How do i redirect only root domain and ignore all wildcard subdomains?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I looked at a bunch of stackoverflow pages and non stackoverflow sites about this and tried a bunch of things. Nothing is working.

I need my-example.net to go to example.com, I need www.my-example.net to go to example.com, I need allothersubdomainsthatarenotwww.my-example.net to be ignored and not do a redirect. I may want to exclude certain other subdomains in the future, that's why one of the attempts has 4 subdomain exceptions, but for now let's concentrate on just ignoring all subdomains except www. www and non-www should go to a different domain. if we can leave the rest of the path intact cool, if not, going to root of the 2nd domain is fine. for example:

```
http://my-example.net/some/path/file.php?parameter=value can go to http://example.com/some/path/file.php?parameter=value, 
but if it's to difficult with wildcard subdomains, then going to http://example.com/ is fine.
```

just so you know, I have other rules in place that handle the wildcard subdomains a specific way and that works fine. some of the attempts seem to work, but break that other rule set i have on the subdomains. for example let's say i have anysubdomain.my-example.net going to my-example.net/folder/file.php?anysubdomain&domain=my-example.net ... then what one or some of the attempts below would do is to make the subdomain do this, which is not what i want: example.com/folder/file.php?anysubdomain&domain=example.com

subdomains should redirect to their own domain with the long path and main domain and www subdomain should redirect to the secondary domain (with or without saving the rest of the path)

Here are my attempts (each line space means new attempt, but in a couple attempts it's not every line that should be uncommented - i was experimenting with variations of the attempts):

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-example\.net$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-example\.net$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^. http://example.com/ [L,R=302]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(my-example\.net)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^. http://example.com/ [L,R=302]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} my-example\.net [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
#Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/ [L,R=301]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
#RewriteRule ^/?(.*)         http://example.com/$1 [L,R,NE]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-example\.net$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.+)\.my-example\.net$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
#RewriteRule .? http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(application|system)
#RewriteRule .? index.php?/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule .? index.php?/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.my-example\.net$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.my-example\.net$ [OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-example\.net$
#RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
# Extract the subdomain part of domain.com
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www)[^.]+)\.my-example\.net$ [NC]
# Check that the subdomain part is not www, dev, old, or new
#RewriteCond %1 !^(www|dev|old|new)$ [NC]
# Redirect all requests to the original url /blog
#RewriteRule ^.*$ /%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Within a VirtualHost clause that mentions `ServerName my-example.net`, configure redirect(s) to example.com.

Within a VirtualHost clause that mentions `ServerName www.my-example.net`, configure it similarly.

The "all other subdomains" part involves both DNS A records (such as "*" wildcard) and Apache config. First, use `dig` or `ping` to see if subdomain "foo" yields your webserver's A (or AAAA) record, that is, see if Apache even gets to make a decision. Then, add a VirtualHost clause for foo, or just rely on Apache's wildcard default matching, to serve a 200 or 302 or 404 document as desired.

DNS controls whether the client's GET request will arrive at port 80 / 443. The client sends a "Host: foo.my-example.net" header in the request. Apache's VirtualHost argument is passed to `strcmp()`, comparing it with the client's "Host:" header. The result of that comparison controls whether the rest of the VirtualHost clause will be used for this request.